# Respecting permissions in getStorage('taxonomy_term')?

Tags: 8, users, taxonomy-terms

**Edit**: *I just realized that Taxonomy permissions are not native to Drupal core, they are the result of a module we activated: [Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term).
(This will explain why they are not being respected by Drupal). The rest of my question still stands though:*

I am able to fetch all the terms in a taxonomy programmatically, by doing the following:

```
$vid = 'TAXONOMY_NAME';
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $tid = $term->id();
   $term_name = $term->name;
   //etc.
}
```

However, I noticed that if I apply "Permissions" to a term, this is not respected. For instance, if a term is limited to "Administrator" only, you will still see it as a "Authenticated User", (non-Administrator).

How can I amend the above code so that it only returns the terms that the logged in user has permissions for?

**Edit**: *I know the answer has to do with using:*

```
$langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$access_check_service = \Drupal::service('permissions_by_term.access_check');
$allowed = $access_check_service->isAccessAllowedByDatabase($TERM_ID, $USER_ID, $langcode);
```

*I'm just not sure of the proper implementation...*

Many thanks!